# Jenkins : Test and build on many labels?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a `Jenkins` setup that have many slaves (using Docker) with different distributions, for example I have 2 labels : `debian-7` and `debian-8`.

When I try to use both labels, it tries to find a slave that have both `debian-7` and `debian-8`.

I would like to **test/build** the project on one slave of each label,

> How can I do this ? So the test/build is both run on debian-7 and debian-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debian-7&&debian-8 = it will require a slave with both label.

debian-7||debian-8 = the job will be launched randomly on one of these two labels.

One solution for you should be to use the [Matrix Combination](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Combinations+Plugin) plugin.

With this plugin, you can a combination to launch your build on the two labels.

[image]

[image]

I think you can also use the [NodeLabel](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) plugin to solve your issue:

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.
Also, yo you know if there is a way to run different commands depending of the OS ? (Like running the deb process on debian and the rpm one on centos ?)

Comment: Maybe you can try this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin and create some script conditions to test the OS version (with uname -a + a grep)